# 'int' object not callable with int(raw_input(" "))

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been looking for a long while, and all the questions in SO about this error are either because a number is being used as a function (i.e. `2(5/3)`) or because a variable is being used as a function or shares name with it (i.e. `functionwithvariablename(3*5)`).

I am getting that error while using a structure like this

```
var=int(raw_input("message: "))
```

Which as far as I know is the correct way of doing it. I have used this same structure several times in the same program and in several classes and modules and I have never had a problem, except with this two lines. [Here](https://github.com/Achifaifa/kirino/blob/master/source/launch.py#L199-L200) is the code (it says `var=input("message")`, but I'm trying to run it now with just those two lines changed). `tempx` and `tempy` don't share names with any function. I have also tried removing the message in `raw_input` (Same result).

I don't know if there is something wrong with the line in particular or I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 11, you define `int = 0`. This overrides the builtin `int`. Change the variable to something else and you should be fine.

Comment: Oh crap, forgot I had those variables in this module. Thanks, that was the problem. I also changed the name of the str variable just in case ;)

Comment: @Achifaifa The hard part in writing an RPG is naming your ability score variables (:

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have over-ridden the built in `int()` and `str()` methods in your code on lines 11 and 15, so they now point to int objects not the built in functions. Hence when you try and call them you get a not callable exception.

It works fine for me on Python 2.7

```
>>> var = int(raw_input("message:"))
message:12
>>> var
12
```